# How to write a loop to populate an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

```
var array = []
for(var outer = 0; outer < maxrows; outer++) {
array[outer] = [];
for(var inner = 1; inner < maxcells; inner++) {
array[outer][inner] = `enter code here`
```

Following this as a guideline, how would I create a self generating array?

Comment: You mean nested arrays?

Comment: Read about [array push](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp).

Comment: `Array.push` causes mutations. Better read about `Array.concat`.